# opening a new window based on the current url of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, button

So ostensibly I'm trying to make a button or a link who's target is contingent on the current page's URL. I'm working on a Wordpress portfolio site that opens up different projects in an Ajax window, but I  also want to be able to link to the separate project page from that window. For instance, if I click the thumbnail for a project titled "Blue" it opens up the project in the ajax window and the url changes to "www.website.com/#blue." Incidentally, the url of the corresponding project page would then be "www.website.com/projects/blue". The idea is to hardcode the button into the Ajax window and write a script that generates the correct URL for the project page so my client doesn't have to copy-paste the code for the button and update the target URL every time she posts a project. This is what I came up with, but I'm not great with Jquery or Javascript and I think something might be wrong with my syntax or the structure of the script. Right now, nothing happens when I press the button.

First it splits the url at each "/" and creates an array from the different strings, then it removes the "#" from the unique string, and opens a new window with the new address.

*EDIT* There were some syntax errors, but it's still not working. Any thoughts on this new version:

```
$(".comment_button").click(function(){
var parse_url = window.location.href.split('/');
var project_name = parse_url[2].replace("#", "");
window.open("http://www.balletinform.com/projects/" + project_name);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want to get is the `#blue` part of the url.

If so, you can use [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/hash).

Your function will then looks like `window.open("http://www.balletinform.com/projects/" + window.location.hash.substring(1));`

Your current function was setting project_name to `"www.balletinform.com"` (`[0]=>"http:"; splitted(/); [1]=>""; splitted('/'); [2]=>"www.balletinform.com"; splitted('/'); [3]=>"#blue")`.
So an alternative solution would have been `var project_name = parse_url[parse_url.length-1].replace("#", "");`

Comment: Yes! That was it. Actually just figured that out myself. Didn't take into account the "http://" as part of the array. I also had the code in the wrong place, so it just wasn't executing at all, regardless. But I got it all working now, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Tried using `a` element ?, with `target="_blank"` attribute ?

```
<a id="blue" href="www.website.com/projects/blue" target="_blank">blue</a>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I do understand the question properly, but I'm not sure either that the problem comes from `window.open` method, but rather from the parsing of the url.

Comment: @Kaiido _"I'm not sure I do understand the question properly, but I'm not sure either that the problem comes from window.open method, but rather from the parsing of the url."_  Popup blocker in browser preventing `window.open()` ? see OP at _"but it's still not working."_ Not certain what "still not working" is describing ?

Comment: Yes that could also be an issue. But if there is a popup blocker, there probably will be an option to open new window in new tabs too, and the anchor solution won't open it in new window.

Comment: @Kaiido Perhaps OP will chime in

Answer (score 0):

```
var new_url=""+(window.location.href).replace('#','projects/');
window.open(new_url);
```

Try replacing # with 'projects/'

Comment: This solution will only work if he does execute it from the main page, if he is already under an other subpath ,e.g `http://www.website.com/new_project/`, it will land users to `http://www.website.com/new_project/project_name`.

Comment: This should actually work as well, the code only executes from clicking the button in the ajax window, wherein the url is always http://www.website.com/#project_name, and the new url that it should always point to would be http://www.websit.com/projcts/project_name.